# How to mount to a Networked Drive Folder with AppleScript in a Domain

Tags: applescript

I have a script written that duplicates most of the home folders (excluding library) to a shared server just for back-up purposes. But i'm confused on how to mount the drive via AppleScript since the shared server folder is on the domain but not actually local. All computers I've tested the script on are connected to the domain directly and not through VPN.

I've tried prompting the user for username and password and then setting them as variables so that I could use them when mounting the drive. But it doesn't work as of this moment. I've tried doing the following.

```
 "smb://domain;" & user_name & "@serverpath/" & user_name &
```

"smb://domain;" & user_name &":"&user_pass& "@serverpath/" & user_name &

I've also tried leaving the domain out of it, which didn't help either. Still getting an error

> Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed.

Answer (score 0):

This Applescript works for me:

```
set usr to "FSB" & "\\" & "u012875902"

set pw to "oblongata"

mount volume "smb://10.111.123.122/servoy" as user name usr with password pw
```

Comment: what's the "\\" & "u12879" part? I don't understand it.

Comment: nevermind, figured you meant the domain. Still getting an error when trying it this way.